# Can perl scripts be executed from within a Gradle script?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to call an existing perl script from within a gradle task?
I've tried searching but can't find anything about it at all, which is surprising (I found stuff about calling gradle from within perl but not the other way around).

Does anybody know if and how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this from the any `GString`.  Example.

```
def process = "perl someScript".execute()
def returnValue = process.waitFor()
println "{$returnValue}: Text from execution: ${process.text}"
```

Comment: Thanks. If the perl script contains several subroutines, how can a specific one be invoked from the gradle script?

Comment: You can't interact with the perl directly but you can call the script with what ever params you want and have the script call your subroutines as needed